# Wrap image around a cylinder

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'd like to add [this effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997344/wrap-an-image-around-a-cylindrical-object-in-html5-javascript) on my fabricjs canvas, is it possible ? I have a background image showing a cylinder, when I add an image, i'd like to "bend" it so that it looks like it is applied on the cylinder, even when I'm moving the image.

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275078/wrap-images-on-papercupbackground-image), but the snippet doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275078/wrap-images-on-papercupbackground-image) will work, its not working because the images are not present in that specified url, change the link.